# add vlan id or mac id to dude to add a network

Tags: network

How to add ONU Machines Vlan ID or MAC ID to the Mikrotik Dude Server?

I am using ccr-1036 to serve internet connection to my users.
we are using vlan id to identify per sub-stations that contains onu.
between ccr and onu there's an olt which grabs the users connection from onu's which identifies with vlan id.
but if there's any way that I can add those vlan id's or those vlan's mac id's to have all sub stations at one place to check if the substation means the onu or specific port of onu is down or up.

Thank You.

Comment: Your post is very confusing, and I really cannot understand what you are asking. Please see the [Network Engineering Question checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question.

Comment: @RonMaupin I've added a bit more details with a direct question. Have a look . . .

Comment: The vendor must offer optional, paid support for a question to be on-topic here. Unfortunately, MikroTik does not offer that. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: @RonMaupin Okay, I'm looking for help there.